# jersey with spring-boot 1.5.14 not working

Tags: rest, spring-boot, jersey

i am trying to make a jersey jax-rs rest project with spring-boot 1.5.14. 
i have used spring jersey starter in dependency. but not working.
Please see my pom beolow.

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.14.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
<dependences>
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependences>
```

Its not working. @Path @Get those all jax-rs anotation is not resolved.
i have added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

then it is resolved. another issue has come.

register(RequestContextFilter.class); is not solved.
then i added---

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.24.1</version>
</dependency>
```

now it is solved but new error comming at runtime.
org/jvnet/hk2/spring/bridge/api/SpringBridge class def not found.
again i have added---

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-bridge</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0-b14</version>
</dependency>
```

now different error has come---
org/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocatorFactory$CreatePolicy class def not found.
again i have added.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
        <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

now it is giving----
org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/binding/AbstractBinder class def not found

i have added h2k api 
again it is giving
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator.
i upgraded hk2 api version . then comming class not found jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Function
i added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>
```

now t last it is giving-"No generator was provided and there is no default generator registered-IllegalArgs exception.

if i ad jeresy all. then it is throwing no implementation found for hibernate validator

Comment: why spring jersey starter cant resolved those dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because you're using `BUILD-SNAPSHOT` for the Spring Boot parent version. If you're going to use a snapshot version, then you need to configure a snapshot repository in your pom. That's why the Jersey starter dependency can't be resolved. What you want to use is the `RELEASE` version. All Spring release version end with this suffix.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.14.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Comment: It shouldn't. Try refreshing the project or restarting your IDE

Comment: yes after giving maven build and refresh compile error has gone but  after removing the spanshot repo and adding release version again showing same error.  "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "java.lang.AbstractMethodError",
    "message": "org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider.initialize(Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator;)V", and more strange why javax.rs is not resolved.

Comment: You shouldn't be getting these errors. Try to [clone this project](https://github.com/psamsotha/jersey-boot-upload-example) and run it. If it works, try to see what you're doing wrong

Comment: yes i downloaded the project. it is spring-boot 2.0.1 . i am using 1.5.14.if i change parent version of spring boot then also ur project giving compilation error for javax.rs

Comment: There's something wrong with you're development environment. I don't have the same problem as you.

Comment: ohh ok then i will try to clear my old local repo and give a fresh build.

Comment: yaaa man it worked for mw after clearing the repo. strange.thanks v much for support.